# Make a windows explorer like html5 menu that automatically adds new files/maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, navigation

I want to make html/javascript/css menu that has the same functionality as windows explorer navigation has.

I have around 200 html files, the only thing is missing that is navigation. I don't need something really fancy. Actually I want the exact same thing as in windows explorer:

[image]

I'm sure that it wouldn't be that difficult to make visually a menu like this using css/javascipt , but what I'm not sure is about this:

Does anybody know some script that automatically converts my file structure into a menu. So that if I add some new page/folder, it would automaticly add this file to the menu. That would save me extremely much time, as I'm planning to add 100's of those files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at these options for jQuery. Some of them do exactly what you want... http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-file-manager-plugins/